# How works the AMP cache system, audience control and integration with paywall systems

Tags: amp-html

We have some questions about Google AMP Project

- We understood that in AMP Project all content is delivered by the Google Cache Servers, like a CDN. That's the correct understanding? How will be controled the cache life time? We'll have any invalidation routine?
- How will be the audience count for the contents delivered by the Google products, when the visitor sees the content directly in the search without visiting our website.
- How works the content delivery for articles that are under a metered-paywall?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently under very active development and we will share the specification later in January.